# IE8 not displaying textarea resize bottom right corner

Tags: javascript, html, css, ie8-browser-mode

I'm using IE8 but the textarea resize bottom right corner is not displaying.  This same code works  ok in Firefox.  I also noticed the same problem in some online examples when using IE.

Anyone knows the trick to display the resize bottom corner in IE?

My CSS:

```
textarea { resize:both; }
```

My HTML:

```
<div>
<textarea rows="20" cols="150"> 

</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So far, the [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/resize) CSS property is only supported by the Gecko and WebKit engines (i.e. Firefox, Chrome and Safari).

Internet Explorer and Opera do not support it (yet).

Comment: The reason being CSS3-UI is [still a Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize) on W3C. Developers and UA vendors avoid the situations like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/25/unprefixed-css3-gradients-in-ie10.aspx) to happen. The sooner W3C decide, the sooner the vendors can implement.

Answer (score 1):

The `resize` CSS attribute isn't supported in Internet Explorer. You may need to use a Javascript framework (such as jQuery) to get truly cross-browser support for this functionality; or you can simply not support it in IE (is it really that important that your users be able to resize the textarea?).